# Using Python logging handler to write log into SimpleGUI multiline

Tags: python, logging

in Python I want to write my own logging.Handler to write the logging output into a GUI. I did this little example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as Sg
import logging

class OutputHandler(logging.Handler):
    window: Sg.Window

    def __init__(self, window: Sg.Window):
        self.window = window

    def emit(self, record):
        self.window["-OUTPUT-"].print(record)


LAYOUT = [
    [Sg.Multiline(default_text="", size=(60, 15), disabled=True, autoscroll=True, key="-OUTPUT-")]
]

main_window = Sg.Window("Test", LAYOUT)

outHandler = OutputHandler(main_window)
log = logging.getLogger("My Logger")
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(outHandler)

log.info("Hello World")
log.warning("This is a warning")
log.error("This is an error")
log.debug("This is for debugging")
```

But when I execute it I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'OutputHandler' object has no attribute 'level'
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    log.info("Hello World")
AttributeError: 'OutputHandler' object has no attribute 'level'
```

I don't see the problem. If I'm using just print() in the emit() method, everything is fine. So what is my problem here?

Comment: Missing `super().__init__()` in your class's init? ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found out that the constructor of logging.Handler is not called.

This solves the problem:

```
class OutputHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, window: Sg.Window):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
```